# Liberar parametro no striptag

Tags: php, funções

Gostaria de colocar uma exceção nessa função, para liberar inserção de `<iframe>`. Essa função que uso para forms gerais, diminui a chance de injections, limpa os espaços e tags porém o usuário quer inserir iframes de youtube, vimeo, gmaps e etc.

Tentei aplicar esse exemplo sem sucesso, onde estou errando?

Modelo:

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

Função:

```
//Valida e cria os dados para realizar o cadastro
private function setData() {

    $this->Data = array_map('strip_tags', $this->Data);
    $this->Data = array_map('trim', $this->Data);
}
```

Comment: O problema é passar o argumento no `array_map()`?

Comment: o problema é declarar quais tags que quero liberar quando aplicar o striptags

Comment: queria fazer algo assim, mas dá erro claro, queria saber como aplicar corretamente.
$this->Data = array_map('strip_tags', $this->Data,'<iframe>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode criar uma função anônima que retorna o `strip_tags()` no `array_map()`.

```
$tags = '<a><p><iframe>';
$arr = ['<a>asdasd</a>', '<p>dois</p>', '<iframe>2015</iframe'];

$novo = array_map(function($item)use($tags){return strip_tags($item, $tags);}, $arr);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a>asdasd</a>
    [1] => <p>dois</p>
    [2] => <iframe>2015
)
```

Comment: Então rray, eu quero q na resposta do array tenha o <iframe>

Comment: @BrunoCoió editei a resposta, faltou um detalhe antes.

Comment: vlw mesmo, era isso, obrigado.